# Struts2 Push Notification/WebSocket Interaction Best Practice

Tags: java, jsp, sockets, model-view-controller, struts2

I am writing a Struts 2 application. In the view, I have a button which triggers an action. That action calls Runtime.exec to launch a process. This process creates a socket over which status updates are sent  (in the form of simple delimited text strings) . I would like these status updates to be reflected in the view.

I know how to write a socket on the server side, but I'm not clear at all on where to incorporate it and how to update the JSP whenever the client sends data on the socket.

Where would I place the server socket: In a listener thread or In the action class that launches the process?

And once I have the status update, what is the best way to update the page?

Also, I would like to update without doing a refresh of the page - I'm supposing to use AJAX for that.

Comment: You can poll the server using AJAX, or use websockets. Tell us what you tried, and what you have difficulties with. And I would indeed listen on a server socket in another, specific thread.

Comment: What's your specific goal?

Comment: My specific goal is to update the view with the status updates received on the socket. So if the process is loading, the interface says as much. It would be a push from the server to the interface.

Comment: What's with the down vote? I'm not asking for code. I want to know, at a high level, what the correct approach is. I've found that I can poll, which in my opinion is resource-consuming and ugly approach, or use something like Comet to push the result. Guess I will research that, but I was hoping for advice on what direction to take

Comment: I think you should be able to use Atmosphere along side struts2 without issue they will simply stand apart.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried StreamHub Community Edition and it looked very promising (just need some tweaking in Javascript on the view and added an observer/listener class to push results), but the license is expired and it looks like streamhub is not well maintained. So I will try Atmosphere. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get this to work with Struts 2 as the filter does not play well with the servlet I ended up building using Atmosphere. Basically I used the Meteor pub sample [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.atmosphere.samples%22%20AND%20a%3a%22atmosphere-meteor-pubsub%22), and modified the servlet to fit our application.

Also, [dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/dojo-websocket) supports websockets. I haven't tested this, but it looks like it could also be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look the example that i have built it using cometd and struts2 on jboss application server https://github.com/harrybabu/struts2-cometd. Hope it helps...